# Program (or Feature of Visual Studio) to allow you to automatically run a set of inputs?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I would like to be able to run a series of inputs automatically to allow for quick and efficient testing. Is there a feature of visual studio, or a program that I could use to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Terminal? I heard they done some bash-like features in powershell, so I think you could just write a script, and run it.

Comment: Hmm do you want to specify a command line for your program in Visual Studio?

Comment: Not sure I follow, I want to run a pre-set set of inputs automatically.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for unit-tests?

Comment: Sorry, what are those? The method suggested in the first comment works perfectly for my needs.

Comment: Wouldn't using a Windows console type batch file be sufficient for this, without the need to use a non-native scripting shell?

Comment: Yup, that was the first suggestion, works really well!